# Listen to real-time changes in Flutter SQFLite Database

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I have a fully functional app created in ***Flutter***. It uses [***sqflite***](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) plugin for storing data. I want to have a data change listener, which will update or refresh the data when new data is added or updated. How can I achieve this. I came across a sqflite helper plugin [***sqlcool***](https://pub.dev/packages/sqlcool) but could not figure out a way to use it with my existing database in sqflite. Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: use https://pub.dev/packages/moor, it says: *"Reactive: Turn any sql query into an auto-updating stream! This includes complex queries across many tables"*

Comment: Thanks @pskink, can you please show me how to do it. I could not get it from their docs.

Comment: see `SimpleSelectStatement` official documentation

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem as yours, and ended up using **Drift (Moor)**.

You can learn about it from its documentation -> https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/getting-started/

It's has similar features as Jetpack Room in Native Android Development. It also notifies when database changes using Flutter Stream API which you can easily observe (subscribe).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve similar function of listening to sqflite changes by implementing Streams, adapting BloC pattern. You can check this [blog post](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/using-streams-blocs-and-sqlite-in-flutter-2e59e1f7cdce/) for a sample. One way of achieving this is by updating the Stream paired to sqflite. With this approach, you can use StreamBuilders that can automatically rebuild child widgets when there's change on Stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can add stream to your data fetching function.

You can learn more about flutter streams from this [link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-stream-basics-for-beginners-eda23e44e32f) .

Answer (score 0):

Consider [this](https://pub.dev/packages/sqlbrite) sqlbrite package, it will allow you to listen to sqlite changes as a stream.