# SQFLite Stream for StreamProvider flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I am using SQFLite for storing data and have difficulties to set up the "listener" for changes. E.g: I have a User model, which is saved in SQFLite. If I delete the row in the DB for this user, I want my app to know about this.

In another project I have used Firebase and it was quite simply to setup StreamProvider as Firebase has everything needed for it. I tried to go through Firebase source code to recreate the same logic for SQFLite, but it's not that easy.

So the question is - how do I create a Stream for my User model so that if the entry is deleted I am notified about it? ( for start, but at the end would be nice to be informed about any changes )

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63109856/listen-to-real-time-changes-in-flutter-sqflite-database